# Does WP query update accept variables being built into it?

Tags: php, mysqli, wordpress

Trying to figure out if this is a WP specific quirk.

The `var_dump` code shows the correct string to be inserted but the `last query` dump at the end shows an incomplete query with no variable being passed it seems. So I'm not sure if this is a WP specific quirk or what could be the issue here? Does anyone have any knowledge on this?

Again the dumps show the correct string until I get to to the query string.

```
$numItems = count($changeorderVar);
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($changeorderVar as $changeorderVartwo ){

          if(++$i === $numItems) {
            $changeorderVarstringFinal .= "'orderfeatured' => ".$changeorderVartwo .''; 
          }
        else 
            $changeorderVarstringFinal .= "'orderfeatured' => ".$changeorderVartwo .','; 

    }
    $numItemsiii = count($updateOrder);
    $iii = 0;
    foreach ($updateOrder as $updateOrdertwo ){

            if(++$iii === $numItems) {
            $updateOrderFinal .= "'orderfeatured' => ".$updateOrdertwo;     
              }
            else 
                $updateOrderFinal .= "'orderfeatured' => ".$updateOrdertwo .',';    
    }
    echo "<div style='background:red;color:#ffffff;'><h1>jsonupdateOrderchangeorderVar = </h1><br /> ";
    var_dump($changeorderVarstringFinal);
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div style='background:red;color:#ffffff;'><h1>jsonupdateOrderchangeorderVar = </h1><br /> ";
    var_dump($updateOrderFinal);
    echo "</div>";



    $wpdb->update( 
                'wp_hnes_table_sar_ram', 
                array($changeorderVarstringFinal),
                array($updateOrderFinal), 
                array('%d','%d','%d'),
                array( '%d','%d','%d' ) 
    );//end update

    exit( var_dump($wpdb->last_query ) );
```

This part of the query is not dynamic yet, but does match the number of elements.

```
array('%d','%d','%d'),
array( '%d','%d','%d' )
```